# Dynamic array formulas not available in office 365 excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have intalled ms office 365.Its registerd.I want try new dynamic array formula.unique ,sort etc.But these formulas not availble.When im trying unique I see only UNICHAR and UNICODE functions only.

Comment: Found [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759): `Note: September 24, 2018: The FILTER function is one of several beta features, and currently only available to a portion of Office Insiders at this time. We'll continue to optimize these features over the next several months. When they're ready, we'll release them to all Office Insiders, and Office 365 subscribers.`

Comment: They are coming but you can op to be part of the beta testers: https://insider.office.com/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

The UNIQUE function is still in Beta testing:

"The UNIQUE function is one of several beta features, and currently only available to a portion of Office Insiders at this time. We'll continue to optimize these features over the next several months. When they're ready, we'll release them to all Office Insiders, and Office 365 subscribers."

This is a link to Microsoft and the official position on this:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e

It does look pretty awesome though.